# FJS Hybrid Pattern Matching Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, pattern-matching

I am a bit of a newbie to Computer Science.
I need to write a FJS algorithm  for pattern matching in java. I Have come across a PDF paper on the matter. But I understood very little from it. I would be very greatful if some one could explain in dummie terms how it works.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a link or reference to the paper you have?

Comment: Sure, Here is the link to the paper: http://cgjennings.ca/papers/franek_jennings_smyth_jda06.pdf

Comment: why this specific algorithm? is this homework? you should mark it a homework if thats the case. Also, you may want to consult your team / guide to help understand this algo if its homework.

Comment: The Franek Jennings Smyth (FJS) algorithm. This is not a homework. and I ahve got it to work for my project but I dint understand the Algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very good with understanding text pattern algorithms, but a quick google search shows [Chris Jennings's website](http://cgjennings.ca/fjs/index.html) which includes both:

- outline of the algorithm (seems cryptic to me)
- C and Java implementations

If this is homework, you're on your own, but if it's not homework, see if you can adapt his implementation to your purposes.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your reply. It is not a homework. I did come across this site and spent couple of hours on it. I did manage to use their code to do what I wanted it to do. However I didnt really understand the algorithem all that well. And that was my question really, Is there a dummie guide to this algorithm.